# SQL - Keep getting an error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Tags: sql

Keep getting an error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Is there an error below?

```
SELECT AVG(salary) AS [Average_Salary],   
CONCAT('$',FORMAT( MIN(salary),2) AS [Minimum_salary],  
concat('$',format ( MAX(salary),2) AS [Maximum_salary]
FROM  Salaries
WHERE (yearID = 1991);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must close the `concat` parenthesis:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) AS [Average_Salary],
CONCAT('$',FORMAT( MIN(salary),2)) AS [Minimum_salary],
concat('$',format ( MAX(salary),2)) AS [Maximum_salary]
FROM  Salaries
WHERE (yearID = 1991);
```

Comment: Thanks,

However after doing that I got this:

Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of format function.

Comment: That's because you're using the `format` function wrongly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: You should be using, for example: `format(min(salary), 'N')`